# How to add path parameter to AWS::Serverless::Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

I have a cloudformation template that generates an API. I want one of the endpoints to have a path parameter. However, I don't understand how I can achieve this with `AWS::Serverless::Function`. Here is my current function:

```
GetItems:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Handler: api/items/get.handler
    Timeout: 29
    CodeUri: .
    Events:
      Get:
        Type: Api
        Properties:
          Method: get
          Path: /items
          RestApiId: !Ref MyAPI
```

This creates an endpoint like `aws-domain-example.com/v1/items`. This works just fine.

However, I want `aws-domain-example.com/v1/items/{item_id}`

How can I add a path parameter?

Comment: changing `Path` in above template like `Path: /items/{item_id}` does not work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe template should be as below. so you can access it as `event.pathParameters.itemCode`

```
      Events:
        Get:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /item/{itemCode}
            Method: get
```